# A solution to the PDE $u_t - \Delta u +\gamma u = 0$ fulfills $|u(x,t)| \le C e^{-\gamma t}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm struggling to solve the following problem:

1. $u_t - \Delta u +\gamma u = 0$ in $\Omega \times (0,\infty)$, where $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$
2. $u = 0$ on $\partial \Omega \times (0,\infty)$
3. $u = u_0$ on $\Omega \times \{0\}$, $u_0 \in C^0(\overline\Omega)$

For a solution $u(x,t)$ to the PDE above, I want to show the following inequality:
$|u(x,t)| \le C e^{-\gamma t}$

If anyone could provide a hint on how to solve this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Write $u=e^{-\gamma t}v$ and notice that $v$ solves $\partial_t v -\Delta v = 0$.

Comment: @JackyChong Thank you for your response! I appreciate your help. However, I'm having difficulty understanding why $v$ is bounded by a constant $C$

Comment: What sort of results do you have access to? Fundamental solutions? Separation of variables? Maximum principles?

Comment: @whpowell96 We've done everything you listed!

Comment: I think that the maximum principles for the heat equation should be enough to show this.

Comment: @whpowell96 Thank you! I've solved it!

Comment: You should writeou your solution as an answer so other usuers can search for it in the future.